# Get particular parts from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get particular parts from a string. I have to get the part which starts after '@' and contains only letters from the Latin alphabet.

I suppose that I have to create a regex pattern, but I don't know how.

```
string test = "PQ@Alderaa1:30000!A!->20000";
var planet = "Alderaa"; //what I want to get
string test2 = "@Cantonica:3000!D!->4000NM";
var planet2 = "Cantonica";
```

There are some other parts which I have to get, but I will try to get them myself. (starts after ':' and is an Integer; may be "A" (attack) or "D" (destruction) and must be surrounded by "!" (exclamation mark); starts after "->" and should be an Integer)

Comment: I find https://regexr.com/ to be a great resource for building and testing regexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the separate parts using capturing groups:

```
@([a-zA-Z]+)[^:]*:(\d+)!([AD])!->(\d+)
```

That will match:

- `@([a-zA-Z]+)` Match `@` and capture in group 1 1+ times a-zA-Z
- `[^:]*:` Match 0+ times not a `:` using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), then match a `:` (If what follows could be only optional digits, you might also match 0+ times a digit `[0-9]*`)
- (\d+) Capture in group 2 1+ digits
- `!([AD])!` Match !, capture in group 3 and A or D, then match !
- `->(\d+)` Match `->` and capture in group 4 1+ digits

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%40%28%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%29%5b%5e%3a%5d*%3a%28%5cd%2b%29!%28%5bAD%5d%29!-%3e%28%5cd%2b%29&i=PQ%40Alderaa1%3a30000!A!-%3e20000%0d%0a%40Cantonica%3a3000!D!-%3e4000NM) | [C# Demo](https://ideone.com/XDWw29)

Comment: wauw that is interesting, i have never really looked into regex patterns, i just just explodes etc.. How does this even work? Does this return an array with results?

Comment: @Livo One way to get the capturing groups is like in this [demo](https://ideone.com/uamwBB) using the [Match.Groups property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful for me!

Comment: @Thefourthbird, thank you for your response! I am testing the regex but why it doesn't match the whole word, only "Cantonic". [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jwAG1Y/3)

Comment: @Ah I see, I have updated it `@([a-zA-Z]+)[^:]*:(\d+)!([AD])!->(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/jwAG1Y/4

Comment: @Thefourthbird, what was the problem? I can't see... :(

Comment: @KaloyanK. This negated character class `[^:]+` has a quantifier of 1+ times which expects at least 1 value so it matched the last `a` in `Cantonica`. I have updated it to `[^:]*` which has a quantifier of 0+ times. So now it matches `Cantonica`. If there are optional digits following Cantonica, you could also use `[0-9]*` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex, which uses a positive look behind to ensure the matched text is preceded by `@` and one or more alphabets get captured using `[a-zA-Z]+` and uses a positive look ahead to ensure it is followed by some optional text, a colon, then one or more digits followed by `!` then either `A` or `D` then again a `!`

```
(?<=@)[a-zA-Z]+(?=[^:]*:\d+![AD]!)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jwAG1Y/2)**

[C# code demo](https://rextester.com/WTGJ39656)

```
string test = "PQ@Alderaa1:30000!A!->20000";
Match m1 = Regex.Match(test, @"(?<=@)[a-zA-Z]+(?=[^:]*:\d+![AD]!)");
Console.WriteLine(m1.Groups[0].Value);

test = "@Cantonica:3000!D!";
m1 = Regex.Match(test, @"(?<=@)[a-zA-Z]+(?=[^:]*:\d+![AD]!)");
Console.WriteLine(m1.Groups[0].Value);
```

Prints,

```
Alderaa
Cantonica
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have a good answers but I would like to add a new one to show named capturing groups.

You can create a class for your planets like

```
class Planet
{
  public string Name;
  public int Value1; // name is not cleat from context
  public string Category; // as above: rename it
  public string Value2; // same problem
}
```

Now you can use regex with named groups

```
@(?<name>[a-z]+)[^:]*:(?<value1>\d+)!(?<category>[^!]+)!->(?<value2>[\da-z]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PxDJjK/2/)

Usage:

```
var input = new[]
{
    "PQ@Alderaa1:30000!A!->20000",
    "@Cantonica:3000!D!->4000NM",
};

var regex = new Regex("@(?<name>[a-z]+)[^:]*:(?<value1>\\d+)!(?<category>[^!]+)!->(?<value2>[\\da-z]+)",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

var planets = input
    .Select(p => regex.Match(p))
    .Select(m => new Planet
    {
        Name = m.Groups["name"].Value, // here and further we can access to part of input string by name
        Value1 = int.Parse(m.Groups["value1"].Value),
        Category = m.Groups["category"].Value,
        Value2 = m.Groups["value2"].Value
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but what does 'p' do in your code snippet and where is it declared or is it like a for loop, declaration inside?

Comment: @Livo `p` is a lambda parameter and it declared "inline". You can rename it to achieve `planet => regex.Match(planet)` and it still will work. Same thing with `m` parameter

Comment: Oh, so you put every input in a p, which seems like some sort of for each, then with p you select m as a new for each and define the planets where p is only where the regex matches and m are the values :D. Thanks!